# Is it possible to hide a password when using `@DataSourceDefinition` (or @MailSessionDefinition)

Tags: jakarta-ee

I would like to use `@DataSourceDefinition` but it is annoying that the password is written without any encryption in the annotation. Is it possible to hide it?

Comment: What app server are you using?  You might be able to just have it in the servers configuration then use a role

Comment: Thanks JGlass for your answer. I know how to configure a data source in my server but the configuration depends on the server and I would like to use the annotation `@DataSourceDefinition` because it will work with any server. The problem is that the password is written in the annotation.

Comment: Yeah, not sure how you're going to get around that - you might be able to obfuscate the code though I've never tried it with J2EE and app servers, only mobile java code.  Obfuscating would hide the password at least